# Jumping on start dragging

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm using dragging by jquery ui and have a strange effect. On start dragging an object it replacing to a new position depend of cursor offset on start dragging. Here [example](http://jsbin.com/wayiharexa/edit?html,css,js,output)
Can somebody help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your html should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="show_dlg" style="display: block;"><div id="zoomimg"><img src="http://mmyers.cloudaccess.net/accelerometer/images/638/1600/piece/Kane_Gold_6.jpg" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: absolute;"></div></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have just removed this part:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(-0.862, -0.744, 0, 22.7734933639967deg); transform: rotate3d(-0.862, -0.744, 0, 22.7734933639967deg); margin-left: -500px; margin-top: -500px; width: 1500px; height: 1500px; max-width: none; left: -179.902038574219px; top: -190.568115234375px;
```

as this is what was causing the problem

Comment: Thank you for advice but transform can't be removed, it's an important part of the script scenario. Thank you

Comment: what is the scenario? because currently that transform is a reason to your jumping (caused by positioning and margins in that block)

Comment: When user mouse move over  image has to transform 3D, if user drag it has to move without jumping. For now I just wrapped it in div and it works, but may be there are any more clear solution?